# How this scaling is done

Tags: scale

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ce0CIRpEqkw) on character modelling but I am stuck at 2:43 how he scale it on y axis.
[image: This is before scaling]

[image: This is after scaling]

But when I scale the same edges my edges become straight unlike his moving inside. How he is doing that scaling ?

Comment: you can enable the Transformation manipulator > Scale mode, on the horizontal menu bar on the bottom, that's how he does it, he just grabs the green handle to scale on the Y axis. But you could also press S and Y to constraint your scale on the Y axis.

Comment: Make sure your Pivot Point is set to "Median Point". I suspect yours is set to "Individual Origins". https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html

Comment: Note: The Z axis is colored Blue; the X axis is colored Red; the Y axis is colored Green. The way you're showing in the pictures you're really scaling the Y axis (see the big green line while you're scaling it). If your intention is to make it smaller in front view, you have to scale it in X axis. S then X.

Comment: Thank you @thibsert

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, press s to engage scaling mode and then press y to choose the y axis, when you move your mouse it will only scale on the y axis. You can do this with x and z also! Make sure with that character, you choose both the back and front or else if you choose one edge only, it will straighten or curve it depending on how you scale it!